# How To Relationship Model Attribute to Table Column In Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, model

I'm developing a system using the **Laravel Framework**. I had create a Model for relationship to my database tables.

My question is, can I relate model attributes to table columns?

For example, following is my Client model:

```
class Client extends Model {

    protected $table = "clients";

}
```

Is it possible for me to access `any_column` with `$client->anyColumn`?

Comment: Try http://laravelsnippets.com/snippets/camel-case-attributes

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your class is extending the [Model](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.0/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php) class which is an Eloquent model. Eloquent provides a simple [ActiveRecord pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_record_pattern) implementation so each column of your database can be accessed with the attribute name in the object that implements it.

Comment: Yes, but if I need attribute name different column name, this is possible?

Comment: Yes, use accessors and mutators to set/get another variable not present in the databse table.